# How do I use grid3d to place three grids along the xy, xz, and yz planes?

Tags: r, rgl

I am using R and rgl.  I would like to add grids along the xy, xz, and yz planes, going through the origin, not along the bounding box.  Something along the lines of this:

[image: 3D graph with grids going through origin]

I'm pretty sure I need grid3d(), but I don't know what arguments to use.

Comment: Did you try the example from the manual? http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/rgl/html/grid3d.html

Comment: @zx8754 - I did, as well as other permutations, but I could not figure out how to get the grids to go through the origin.  I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: Please add code as well, so we know where to pick it up from.

Comment: @zx8754 - I'll do so when I get home, but my attempts at using `grid3d()` consist of me flailing around =)

Comment: I've updated the question to show a much better example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 3)
plot3d(xyz, axes = FALSE)
abclines3d(x = matrix(0, ncol=3), a = diag(3), col="black", lwd=3)
grid3d("x", at = list(x = 0), col = "blue")
grid3d("y", at = list(y = 0), col = "red")
grid3d("z", at = list(z = 0), col = "green")
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!